# Iteration and Selecting Those Unique Numbers (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, yaml

Scope of what I am trying to do: Various numbers of FAQ's are being pulled in upon build via yaml file which will have only the Question showing by default and then upon click the appropriate Answer will show.

I have figured out how to add a unique class for each question and each answer but I can't figure out how to toggle answer1 when question1 is clicked.

I appreciate any help! I am still learning javascript/jquery and get lost easily so if you could help explain or point to documentation of what I am missing I would appreciate it!

https://jsfiddle.net/texobyte/jns7v9ox/

```
$(".faqQuestion").each(function (i) {
    $(this).addClass("question" + (i + 1));
});
$(".faqAnswer").each(function (i) {
    $(this).addClass("answer" + (i + 1));
});


$("#toggle-faq h5").hide();
$("#toggle-faq").click(function () {
    $("#toggle-faq h5").slideToggle("slow", function () {});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also try this (after changing the id "toggle-faq" to a class, as the other answer says):

```
$(".toggle-faq h5").hide();

$(".toggle-faq").on('click', function () {

    if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
        $(this).children("h5").slideToggle();
        $(this).removeClass("active");
        return;
    }

    $(".active").children("h5").slideToggle();
    $(".active").removeClass("active");

    $(this).addClass("active");
    $(this).children("h5").slideToggle();

});
```

The "this" means that it will only toggle the .toggle-faq that has been clicked on, and not all of them.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked on you Fiddle and made few modifications to make it working. Here is the [**LINK**](https://jsfiddle.net/_vijaydev/jns7v9ox/1/)

I have replace `id="toggle-faq"` with `class="toggle-faq"`; we should not repeat ids:

```
<div class="toggle-faq">
```

Also replaced this code:

```
$("#toggle-faq h5").hide();
$("#toggle-faq").click(function () {
     $("#toggle-faq h5").slideToggle("slow", function () {});
});
```

With a better and working code:

```
// hide all answers at first
$( '.faqAnswer' ).hide();

$( '.toggle-faq' ).on('click', function () {
    var $this = $(this);

    // if this is already open
    if ( $this.hasClass('active') ) {
        return;
    };

    // close any other already open...
    if ( !!currentSelected ) {
        currentSelected.find( '.faqAnswer' ).slideToggle( 'slow' );
    };

    // ...and then open the clicked item
    $this.find( '.faqAnswer' )
        .slideToggle( 'slow', function () {

            // now, make sure this is currentSelected
            currentSelected = $this;
        });
});
```

Let me know if you have any doubts. Good luck, have fun!